# Ruby on Rails Devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to use the devise gem for my rails 3.2 project, but when I try to check for the sign_in page, I am getting the following error:

```
wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
```

Extracted source (around line #3):

```
<h2>Sign in</h2>

<%= form_for(resource_name, resource, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <p><%= f.label :email %></p>
    <p><%= f.text_field :email %></p>
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a wrong number of arguments to the `form_for` method as it accepts only 2 arguments.

See http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for for documentation on this method.

Chances are that you should have written line 3 as:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```